# Jquery Toggle Text, Selecting all instances

Tags: jquery

So the problem I'm having is I have this Div "Reply" and inside of it is an h1 tag with the word Hide in it.  The word Hide is wrapped in a span tag with the class of "Toggle"  I have Jquery code which basically says everytime you click on the Div it will toggle the hide text in the span tag to show and of course if you click again it will revert back to normal, The problem I have is that I have multiple instances of these classes and its changing the text for the other ones.  I wonder if there is a way in jquery to only toggle the specific one im clicking on while keeping all my other classes the same (because I need to reuse them a lot).

Jquery

```
  $('.Reply').toggle (
    function()  { $("span.Toggle").html("Show");}
    ,function()  { $("span.Toggle").html("Hide");}
   );
```

HTML

```
<div class="Reply">
  <h1><span class="Toggle">Hide</span> This Text</h1>
</div>

<div class="Reply">
  <h1><span class="Toggle">Hide</span> This Text</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `this` as the [context in the selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) so it only changes the toggle inside current clicked div

```
$('.Reply').toggle( function () {
  $("span.Toggle", this).html("Show");
}, function () {
  $("span.Toggle", this).html("Hide");
});
```

the context selector works exactly like the [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).find("span.Toggle")
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/wd9y4/)

Comment: Thank you SO much it works great,  I had a feeling it was the 'this' selector but I wasnt sure how to write it (I am very new to Jquery). thanks a ton.